# Can I get mapping as output from SatisfiabilityInstances?

Tags: output, rule, boolean-computation, logic

Consider the code:

```
SatisfiabilityInstances[Implies[a, b], {a, b}, All]
(* output *) {{True, True}, {False, True}, {False, False}}
```

I would like to obtain the following output instead, similar to how `Solve` works:

```
{{a -> True, b -> True}, {a -> False, b -> True}, {a -> False, b -> False}}
```

I came up with the following solution:

```
vars = {a, b}
SatisfiabilityInstances[Implies[a, b], vars, All]
Thread[vars -> #] & /@ %
(* output *) {{a -> True, b -> True}, {a -> False, b -> True}, {a -> False, b -> False}}
```

But it feels somewhat clumsy. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Your method seems very reasonable - wrap it in a function and away you go! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your method is extremely reasonable. Here it is in a small function:

```
satisfiabilityInstancesRules[expr_, vars_] := 
 Thread[vars -> #] & /@ SatisfiabilityInstances[expr, vars, All]
```

and now:

```
satisfiabilityInstancesRules[Implies[a, b], {a, b}]
```

> ```
> {{a -> True, b -> True}, {a -> False, b -> True}, {a -> False, b -> False}}
> ```

```
satisfiabilityInstancesRules[Or[a, b, c], {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {{a -> True, b -> True, c -> True}, {a -> False, b -> True, 
>       c -> True}, {a -> False, b -> False, c -> True}, {a -> True, 
>       b -> False, c -> True}, {a -> False, b -> True, 
>       c -> False}, {a -> True, b -> True, c -> False}, {a -> True, 
>       b -> False, c -> False}}
> ```

Comment: OK, I thought there is perhaps some parameter to just do that. It seems like Mathematica is a bit inconsistent with the solver outputs.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I expected that as well but found nothing useful. I suppose this will do for now - you could consider emailing WRI support with a feature request.